# Apply function to rows of Dataframe relying on previous function results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to iterate the rows of pandas DataFrame and apply a function to rows one by one. The input value of the function depends on the results of the previous row.

Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math


def predict_loc(df, lon, lat):
    R = 6378.1  # Radius of the Earth
    brng = np.deg2rad(df.wdir)  # Bearing is radians.
    d = df.wspd * df.delta * 60 / 1e3  # Distance in km

    lat2 = math.asin(
        math.sin(lat) * math.cos(d / R)
        + math.cos(lat) * math.sin(d / R) * math.cos(brng)
    )

    lon2 = lon + math.atan2(
        math.sin(brng) * math.sin(d / R) * math.cos(lat),
        math.cos(d / R) - math.sin(lat) * math.sin(lat2),
    )

    lat2 = np.rad2deg(lat2)
    lon2 = np.rad2deg(lon2)

    return lon2, lat2


dates = pd.date_range("20130101", periods=6, freq="1H")
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(6, 3),
    index=dates,
    columns=[
        "wdir",
        "wspd",
        "delta",
    ],
)

lon = 0
lat = 1

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    lon, lat = predict_loc(row, lon, lat)
```

In this example, the initial values of lon and lat are 0 and 1, respectively.
Then, the location is predicted by the `predict_loc` function. The new lon and lat are the inputs for the next row. What I want is the final lon and lat.

Is there a quicker way to finish this task? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, by "quicker way to finish the task", do you mean that you're looking to simplify `predict_loc` or that the function is fine as it is, but you are looking for something faster than `iterrows()`?

Comment: Hi @Laurent, I mean something faster than `iterrows()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as it is, your code runs in **0.0002 second** in average:

```py
import statistics
import time

np.random.seed(0)  # In order to get consistant results

iterations = 25_000

elapsed_time = []
for i in range(iterations):
    start_time = time.time()
    lon = 0
    lat = 1
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        lon, lat = predict_loc(row, lon, lat)
    elapsed_time.append(time.time() - start_time)

print(lon, lat)
# 6861.350646683788 -63.005854847412145
print(f"--- {statistics.mean(elapsed_time):2f} seconds in average ---")
# --- 0.000233 seconds in average ---
```

At this point of your work, given the fact that you are only interested in the final results, you don't need Pandas and I would suggest using Python instead by slightly modifying `predict_loc` and defining a helper function that manipulates `lists` instead of `Series`, like this:

```py
def new_predict_loc(*args):
    wdir, wspd, delta, lon, lat = args
    R = 6378.1  # Radius of the Earth
    brng = np.deg2rad(wdir)  # Bearing is radians.
    d = wspd * delta * 60 / 1e3  # Distance in km

    lat2 = math.asin(
        math.sin(lat) * math.cos(d / R)
        + math.cos(lat) * math.sin(d / R) * math.cos(brng)
    )

    lon2 = lon + math.atan2(
        math.sin(brng) * math.sin(d / R) * math.cos(lat),
        math.cos(d / R) - math.sin(lat) * math.sin(lat2),
    )

    lat2 = np.rad2deg(lat2)
    lon2 = np.rad2deg(lon2)

    return lon2, lat2


def compute_coordinates(df):
    n = 0
    wdir = df["wdir"].to_list()
    wspd = df["wspd"].to_list()
    delta = df["delta"].to_list()
    lon, lat = 0, 1

    while n < df.shape[0]:
        lon, lat = new_predict_loc(wdir[n], wspd[n], delta[n], lon, lat)
        n += 1
    return lon, lat
```

That way, the computation is executed in **0.00003 second** in average, which is nearly **7 times faster** than previously:

```py
elapsed_time = []
for i in range(iterations):
    start_time = time.time()
    lon, lat = compute_coordinates(df)
    elapsed_time.append(time.time() - start_time)

print(lon, lat)
# Same results as before
# 6861.350646683788 -63.005854847412145
print(f"--- {statistics.mean(elapsed_time):2f} seconds in average ---")
# --- 0.000027 seconds in average ---
```

Comment: Thanks! Ha, I don't know the loop of `while` is faster than the row loop. Is that caused by the reading of row data or something else?

Comment: Probably, yes. Compared with lists, there is the overhead of getting rows and that of accessing values with dot notation.